# Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, vite

I'm building a project using react + vite + sass. Whenever I run the code using "npm run dev", I get this error "[plugin:vite:css] Preprocessor dependency "sass" failed to load: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')". Please help me

I don't know what to do